# AngularJS todoapp displaying as the variable name in webpage

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm following a tutorial online, but when I refresh my browser I get {{todo.title}} and the checkbox doesn't put a line through the text if clicked.
Any ideas why. I don't see anything different from my code and the video I'm following.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="ToDo">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>todo</title>
      <style>
         .done{text-decoration: line-through;color:#ccc;}
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div ng-controller='todoController'>
         <form name="frm" ng-submit="addTodo()">
            <input type="text" name = "newtodo" ng-model="newtodo" required>
            <button ng-disabled="frm.$invalid">Go</button>
         </form>
         <button ng-click="clearCompleted()">Clear Completed</button>
         <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">
               <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done" />
               <span ng-class="{'done': todo.done}">{{todo.title}}</span>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <script scr="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script> 
         angular.module('ToDo', []).
         controller('todoController', ['$scope', function($scope){
            $scope.todos = [{'title': 'Build a todo app', 'done':false}];
            $scope.addTodo = function(){};
            $scope.clearCompleted = function(){};
         }]);
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: browser console will probably contain errors relating to not loading angular or one of its dependencies or your controller js file.

Comment: It says index.html:29 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined. But that doesn't make sense to me because line 29 is angular.module('ToDo', []);

Comment: Sounds like angularjs isn't included in index.html

Comment: <script scr="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
 leads to the angular.min.js file. Am I forgetting something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please include angularjs file like below. because u not included path of AngularJS Library

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>todo</title>
<style>
.done{text-decoration: line-through;color:#ccc;}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: he just misspelled `src` as `scr`

Answer (score 2):

you have misspelled `src` as `scr`

```
 <script scr="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer if you are using bower.